# how to draw circles inside circles

Tags: tikz-pgf

I'm learning how to use TikZ/PGF. I want to draw this picture :

[image]

Here's how I began :

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[frenchb]{babel}  
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric,arrows,positioning,fit,calc,}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \node (sun) at (0,0) [circle, fill=yellow, radius=0.3cm]{};
        \node (sunlabel) [above=0.08 of sun]{Sun};
        \node (root) at (0,0) [draw, circle, radius=3cm]{};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The problem is that the second circle is not drawn. I don't know what's the problem. This syntax work but I don't know how to give a name to the circles and how to fill a circle with a color.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[frenchb]{babel}  
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric,arrows,positioning,fit,calc,}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \draw (0,0) circle [radius=.3cm, fill=yellow];
        \draw (0,0) circle [radius=2cm];
         \path[
            %rotate=-15.2,
            postaction={
                decoration={
                    text along path,
                    text={%
                        OORT CLOUD
                    },
                    text align=center,
                    reverse path
                },
                decorate
            }
        ]
         (-27:2.2cm) arc (-27:210:2.2cm);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Z order does matter here. If the top circle is bigger than the bottom one, the bigger one will hide the bottom one when you add fill color to the bigger one and set its opacity to 1.

Comment: This isn't an answer to your question, but [this](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/116978/drawing-of-sunearthmoon-system) may be of interest.

Comment: In your first code snippet, `radius` has no effect because it is not a valid option for `\node`.

Comment: [Design of an asteroid belt in TikZ](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/123847/14500) is another answer that may be of interest...

Comment: I'm curious how long it takes until the first physically correct animated answer will be posted

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You will need to put the accented characters in braces in the `circle label` because PGF will split the string into tokens and will therefore split the accents from the characters, which leads to weird errors.

I translated the labels to french to emphasize the behaviour (I don't speak french, so I hope I didn't make too many mistakes).

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenx}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.text}
\begin{document}
\sffamily
\begin{tikzpicture}[
        white,
        ultra thick,
        planet/.style = {draw,fill,circle,inner sep=#1},
        circle label/.style = {
            postaction={
                decoration={
                    text along path,
                    text = {#1},
                    text align=center,
                    text color=white,
                    reverse path,
                },
            decorate,
        }
        }
    ]
    \filldraw[black] (-7,-7) rectangle (7,8);
    \node at (0,7.5) {\bfseries\Large Voisins les plus proches du soleil};
    \path[circle label={Nuage d'Oort}] (0,-1.2) arc (-90:360-90:1.2);
    \draw[dotted] (0,0) circle (1);
    \foreach \i in {2,4,6} {
        \path[circle label={\i\ Ann{é}e lumi{è}res}] (0,-\i-.2) arc (-90:360-90:\i+.2);
        \draw (0,0) circle (\i);
    }
    \node[yellow,planet=3pt,label={above:Soleil}] at (0,0) {};
    \node[red,planet=3pt,label={[text width=1.5cm,align=right]0:Proxima Centauri déc.\ 1917}] at (44:4.3) {};
    \node[yellow,planet=4pt,label={[text width=2.5cm,align=center]90:Alpha Centauri déc.\ 1917}] at (50:4.3) {};
    \node[red!50!black,planet=2pt,label={[text width=2.5cm,align=center]0:WISE 1049-5319 déc.\ 2013}] at (54:6.3) {};
    \node[red!50!black,planet=2pt] at (57:6.3) {};
    \node[red,planet=3pt,label={[text width=3cm,align=center]95:L'étoile de Bernard déc.\ 1916}] at (125:6) {};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

> [image]

Comment: Ok thanks. I know the solution to get the light years sloped to the circle

Comment: look at my updated question. Do you know how to not draw all the circle like in picture?

Comment: I can't replace `LIGHT YEARS` with `Année lumières`. The special characters are the problem. Do you know how to solve the problem?

Comment: @user230137: I think you should try loading `\usepackage[<encoding>]{inputenc}` where `<encoding>` should be very likely `utf8`.

Comment: @ClaudioFiandrino NO I found a solution. Special characters should written like this {éà}.

Comment: @user230137: if you are able to use `é` and it is correclty displayed in PDF output without `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}`, I will be happy to know the secret :)

Comment: @ClaudioFiandrino No I used the package but if I don't put it between `{}` it won't work. You can use another package and use `{\'e}` this syntax.

Comment: @user230137: thanks, I know both approaches. However, it should work even without groups around `é`.

Comment: @HenriMenke The translation are correct. You only should put `Nuage d'Oort`.

Answer (score 2):

If you use the syntax:

```
\draw [fill=yellow] (0,0) circle (0.3cm) node (sun) {};
```

then things work as expected:

[image]

### Notes:

- I added a `draw=none` for the sun as you probably don't want a border around it.
- I left you original lines as comments so you can see the differences.

### Code:

```
\documentclass[border=2pt]{standalone}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[frenchb]{babel}  
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric,arrows,positioning,fit,calc,}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        %\node (sun) at (0,0) [circle, fill=yellow, radius=0.3cm] {};
        \draw [fill=yellow, draw=none] (0,0) circle (0.3cm)
            node (sun) {};
        \node (sunlabel) [above=0.08 of sun]{Sun};
        %\node (root) at (0,0) [draw=red, circle, radius=3cm] {};
        \draw [draw=red, ultra thick] (0,0) circle (3.0cm)
            node (planet) {};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

Fewer keystrokes with PSTricks.

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=12pt]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}(-2,-2)(2,2)
    \pscircle*[linecolor=orange]{5pt}
    \pscircle{2}
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]