# How can I draw a Venn diagram with multiple circles contained in a circle?

Tags: tikz-pgf, draw, venn-diagrams

Exactly like [image: this.] I can't figure out where to start. I don't know why Tikz confuses me so much.

Comment: Related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/176089/how-to-draw-circles-inside-circles?rq=1

Answer (score 7):

Welcome to TeX.SE! The way this site is meant to work is that if you have problems with some TeX code, you can post it in form of a so-called [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that), i.e. a minimal document that starts with `\documentclass` and ends with `\end{document}` along with some information on where you got stuck. However, as you are new here, I'd like to give you a start, hoping that you find the time to try something yourself and find out how much more fun it is.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[font=\sffamily]
\foreach \X [count=\Y starting from 2] in {C,B,A}
{\draw (-\Y,-\Y/2) circle ({1.5*\Y} and \Y);
\node at (1-2*\Y,-1.1*\Y) {class \X}; }
\draw ([xshift=-0.5cm,yshift=-0.5cm]current bounding box.south west)
rectangle ([xshift=0.5cm,yshift=0.5cm]current bounding box.north east);
\node[anchor=south] at (current bounding box.north) {Three classes};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Of course there are dedicated packages for that, allowing you to do much more sophisticated things, just a Google search away.

Comment: +1 for the foreword :)